# Input text value for specific words

Tags: php, validation, input, textfield

I have a text field in a contact form, users have to reply to a simple question (I know is not the best way to approach spam, we already have other things captcha, honeypots and more).

The question is that I just want to give the user the option of 2 answers.

```
    if ($_POST['answer'] == "banana") {
        // we're OK, do something
    } else {
       alert("YOU FAILED!!!");
    }
```

I want the text field to pass with more than 1 word, let's say "foo" and "baz"

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: To clarify: do you want to pass two words with the same POST name variable or do you want to compare the single POST value to 2 possible options with OR condition?

Comment: i changed the POST name, it was just an example, ist not being used liked that
I want to be able to submit the form, with either of the 2 answers.

Comment: `if (in_array($_POST['answer'], ['banana', 'platano'])) {`

Comment: @GregSchmidt thank you so much! this worked perfect!

Comment: @GregSchmidt Please post an answer as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @BodoThiesen, I didn't have time to write it up as a proper answer at the time, but wanted to give the poster help in a timely manner. Thanks for the reminder to come back and add context to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tim (indirectly) suggests using a logical operator. A solution using that would look like this:

```
if ($_POST['answer'] == 'banana' || $_POST['answer'] == 'platano') {
```

That's the way to go if the conditions you need to check are unrelated to each other (e.g. if you needed to check values from two different form fields). But in your case, I'd recommend checking whether the provided value is in a list of acceptable values:

```
if (in_array($_POST['answer'], ['banana', 'platano'])) {
```

This is slightly shorter code (and, I'd argue, more readable, and hence more maintainable) in the two-value case, but gets successively better and better if you find that you need to add third and fourth options.